# WP: count posts sharing same tag?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hails!

I am new to WP codex. Here's an example of code I have come up with to retrieve tags for a specific post:

```
<?php
        global $post;

        $post_tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
        if ($post_tags) {       
            foreach($post_tags as $tag){
            echo '<div class="tag"><a href="' . get_site_url() . '/tag/'    .   $tag->name  . '">' . $tag->name . '</a></div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

The question is - how to check is a tag is also shared with at least one other post (to show a tag only if there are at least two posts with the same tag)? Basically what I need is this:

```
if ($post_tags **AND $post_tags_count > 1**) {  do the rest of the code
```

I know it should be simple but was unable to find how. 
PS:  $post_tags_count - just an example to show that I have to count posts sharing the same tag.

I believe I  could add a loop with $count = 0; $count++; But maybe there is a better solution provided by WP? Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have figured that out myself. Hopefully it will be useful for someone:

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $post_tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);

    if ($post_tags) {       
        foreach($post_tags as $tag){

        $tag_count =  $tag->count;
        if($tag_count > 1){
            echo '<div class="tag"><a href="' . get_site_url() . '/tag/'    .   $tag->name  . '">' . $tag->name . '</a></div>';

        }
    }
}
?>
```